# Error when export AWS Aurora (PostgreSQL) to S3

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-aurora

I have error when export AWS Aurora (PostgreSQL) to S3:
`could not upload to Amazon S3 DETAIL:  Amazon S3 client returned 'curlCode: 28, Timeout was reached'.`

I have created IAM, Policies and attach it to Aurora to access to S3.
I need some help! Thank you!

I need aurora export to csv file and save it to S3

Comment: How are you performing the export? Did you follow the steps shown on [Exporting data from an Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster to Amazon S3 - Amazon Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html)? See also the 'Troubleshooting access to Amazon S3' section on that page.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).